# What machine learning method can be used to predict next element in a sequence?(101001000100001...)

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, sequence

This problem is looking hard to solve with classical machine learning methods, even for deep neural networks

so, the idea is to predict next element in the following sequence
`1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0x6 1 0x7 1 ... 1 0xN`

What is the suitable method(if it exists so far) to solve this problem?

Comment: No method based on patterns will work, because the pattern grows unboundedly. You need symbolic methods (finding formulas that match).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming - please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [LSTM's (Long Short Term Memory)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_short-term_memory). They are specifically designed for doing predictive classifications by processing multiple sequences of data. Here is a [great Medium post](https://medium.com/@nutanbhogendrasharma/simple-sequence-prediction-with-lstm-69ff0f4d57cd) that provides an introduction to LSTM's and a short example.